# Pointer to one single char of a two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, argv

As far as I know, an array like

> int example[10]

Is nothing else than a pointer to the first element in this array.

> char* argv[]

Is an array of pointers; so that should be pointers which point to other pointers.

I have following problem now:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  double ptrarg2=argv[2][1];
  printf("beginletter=%c\nbeginpos=%d\n",&ptrarg2, ptrarg2);
  return 0;
}
```

I am starting the program with `./program test` and expecting the output to be:

```
beginletter=c
beginpos=123213123
```

While `123213123` should be the adress where the c is actually stored.

I am actually getting:

```
beginletter=
beginpos=0
```

what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you miss something in the command arguments? or you should minus 1 to your numbers.

Comment: No, `int example[10]` declares an array object, not, I repeat *not*, a pointer object. Arrays are not pointers. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), particularly question 6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&ptrarg2` is the address of the local variable, which is not the address that you are expecting.  Just use `argv[1][0]` and `argv[1]`.  `argv[1][0]` will give you the first character of the first argument, and `argv[1]` will give you the pointer to the first argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{      
  printf("beginletter=%c\nbeginpos=%p\n",argv[1][0], argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: very nice Thank you!! could you explain me what a negative adress means? I expected it to be like this for example: t@111 and e@112 s@113  but it is: t@-1080558759 and e@-1080558758

Comment: The reason is that you are interpreting memory address as a signed digit with `"%d"`.  Memory address should use `"%p"` instead.

Comment: i love you! Thank you very very very much!!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `argv[0]` is going to be `"./program"`, `argv[1]` is going to be `"test"`, and `argv[2]` is going to be undefined or NULL because you don't have three arguments. The value of `argc` should tell you how many items there are in `argv[]`. My guess in this case is that the answer will be 2, and therefore only the first two (`argv[0]` and `argv[1]`) are valid.

There are several other strange things going on here. `ptrarg2` is declared as a double, not as a char; the behavior here would be to convert the character to its floating point numeric equivalent and store that. Perhaps you meant `ptrarg2` to be a char?

Next up, the `printf()` doesn't correspond very well to its additional arguments. `&ptrarg2` is a `double *`, but you're assigning it to a `%c` (character) field, not a `%p` (pointer) field. `ptrarg2` is a `double`, but you're assigning it to a `%d` (decimal number) field, not a `%lf` (long float, aka double) field. `printf` will happily try and print out values even when your types don't match, but they will be wrong, and crashing is quite possible.

Comment: changing double ptrarg2=argv[1][1]  returns me a random char and the position 0 :S

Comment: See my additional comments. You have problems with your printf and the type of ptrarg2 as well.